# Не получается поднять docker compose - Ошибка ReadTimeoutError pip docker

Tags: docker, pip

Прохожу туториал по докеру, пытаюсь поднять docker-compose, Dockerfile следующего вида -

```
FROM python:alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install pymongo

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

При попытке скачать pymongo pip выдает ошибку - 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pymongo/

Нахожусь не за прокси, проблем с сетью нет(манипуляции с опцией --default-timeout успеха не возымели). Правда, очевидно они есть у pip внутри докера. Даже не знаю куда копать.
Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
Docker Compose version v2.16.0
pip 20.0.2
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Покажите ваш `docker-compose.yaml`. Сам по себе `Dockerfile` нормальный. Я попробовал его собрать - получилось, `pip` отработал успешно.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BhZq7zFD

Comment: У меня `docker-compose build` сработал. Проверьте у себя файервол, может быть докеру запрещено выходить в сеть.

Comment: Спасибо за потраченное время, оказывается я просто сломал pip.